# Why is karpas usually parsley?

Tags: food, passover-seder-hagada

Apparently, a [variety of vegetables](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6503/5275) my be used for karpas. So, when and why has it become common to use parsley?

Comment: Because you've usually been at Sedarim with parsley? Why do you think most people have your experience? I've seen radish, celery, potato or banana used.

Comment: I always thought celery ,some have custom of onion  (but problematic for bracha)

Comment: @DoubleAAd,or pineapple

Comment: OU say in general kashrus guidance  "Please note: Curly leaf parsley is very difficult to check. It is therefore recommended that only flat leaf parsley be used."

Comment: @DanF -- You mean common among Ashkenazim.  We used celery.

Comment: Ashkenazi. We use potatoes or celery.

Comment: Is it common? I thought more common was potato? I use onion

Comment: Hi @Dude - I can see raw oninon as being more problematic than parsley based on the reasoning, above. Not too many people eat straight raw onions b/c of their sharpness.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I was at a seder that used parsley. I usually use potatoes.

Comment: @DanF raw onions are commonly eaten in salad. so you aren't correct

Comment: @Dude Got you, on that. I think I had asked a question on M.Y. a while ago if the bracha on a raw vegetable changes only when it is used as an "additive" to a mixture such as a salad, or whether it is mixed with a dressing. E.g. generally, in the U.S., people don't eat raw cabbage unless it is part of cole slaw. So, same question may apply to the onions. I have to see if I can locate this question.

Comment: Why do so many Americans think putting a piece of parsley on the plate makes it fancy?  It's common in restaurants too (well, used to be).  I'm guessing it's because it's different from plain salad but also readily available.  It's also easy to portion, has a long stalk perfect for dipping, and it holds saltwater well (at least the curly does).  It also tastes good.  Based on the comments though, I wonder if this is a mostly American thing.

Comment: @Cyn From my understanding, a lot of the garnish concepts comes from catering. Flowers and fauna are meant to please the eyes, and about 85% of eating is based on sight and smell. If the food doesn't look good, you won't eat it even if it tastes fine. Of course, tulips and daisies have toxins that would prob. ruin the food. Hence, cabbages, kale and lettuce leaves tend to rein as decoration - in France, I gather, moreso than in U.S. Parsley is common because it's small, easy to handle and maneuver, doesn't require cutting, and moreso, can sit well on small foods better than lettuce leaf.

Comment: I always heard the parsley was there to freshen your breath (before? during? after?) but I have no idea if that was an actual reason for the trend.  But yeah, it's also about making the plate look pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Because its green and sprigy, symbolizing the new growth of springtime. Source:my kids Pesach workbooks.

Comment: So is cucumber, tomatillo, green bell pepper, jalapeno, scallion, celery, asparagus, okra and honeydew.

Comment: @DoubleAA see edit

Comment: Cucumber, tomatillo, bell pepper (even green ones), jalapeño, okra, and honeydew are summer produce and don't ripen in spring time (for Northern hemisphere temperate and Mediterranean climates). @DoubleAA

Answer (score 0):

Magen Abraham 473 sk 4

> ואני תמה למה נהיגי במדינתינו ליקח פעטערזיל"ן ואפשר דס"ל שע"י הבשר הם משביחין כמש"ש ולפי מש"ש בשם תר"י דוקא כשאין נאכלין כלל חיין מברך שהכל אבל כשנאכלין חיין אף ע"פ שטובים יותר מבושלים מ"מ מברך כשהן חיין בפה"א א"כ א"ש, ומ"מ דעתי חוכך בזה למה בחרו בדבר שיש בו פלוגתא ה"ל ליקח ירק אחר ואפשר ששאר ירקות אין מצוים כ"כ בימי הפסח א"נ משום דבגמרא נזכר ירק ושאר דברים נקראו לפת והירק שלנו אין נאכל כמו שהוא חי אא"כ כבוש וזה אינו מצוי בפסח ובטור וגמ' אי' שגם על מרור מברך בפה"א וצ"ל דמרור שלהם הי' ראוי לאכול חי כמו לטי"ך עס"ה: ‏

The Magen Avraham was surprised why in his country people used parsley for Karpas. He says that there is a machloket (1) and according to some poskim, to eat is raw and bless adama is wrong. He says that perhaps there are few vegetables in this season, or because Gemara calls Karpas vegetable, and most vegetables we eat are called condiments for bread. Other species that are called vegetables are eaten in brine. So parsley is one of the rare species that are called vegetables and are eaten raw, not in brine.

---

(1):  There are poskim who state that if one vegetable is preferentially eaten cooked, one says adama when it's cooked an shehakol when it's raw. But talmide Rabenu Yona sais that if it's edible raw, we say adama even when it's raw

Comment: I saw this answer in one of the other questions on M.Y. There's a piece of MA puzzle that puzzles me. (Did I puzzle you more?) Isn't *adma* said on anything growing from the ground including herbs? Unless he suggests that it was uncommon to eat this raw, then. However, this crosses the "border" in that raw parsley is used commonly now as salad toppings and garnish. In tabouleh, most notably, sometimes the majority is parsley and it is raw.

Comment: Tavlin is an other function as in tabulet. We needs something eaten alone as lettuce, cited on the end of the sayif katan

Comment: There are poskim who state that if one vegetable is preferentially eaten cooked, one says adama when it's cooked an shehakol when it's raw. But talmide Rabenu Yona sais that if it's edible raw, we say adama even when it's raw.